# How do I poll a database and populate a controller using AngularJs, Ui-Router, and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I've been trying to get my Angular app to populate the controller with data from a database (mongodb) before the page loads. I can't quite get it to work. I'm trying to use the "resolve" property of angular ui-router but it's not working and I can't figure it out!!

Here's the full code for my app:

```
var freezerApp = angular.module('freezerApp', ['ui.router']);



    freezerApp.config([
    '$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
      controller: 'freezerCtrl',


    });




    $stateProvider
    .state('freezer', {
      url: '/freezers',
      templateUrl: 'partials/freezers.html',
      controller: 'freezerCtrl',
      //not working:


      resolve: {
        freezerPromise: function($scope){
      return $scope.getAll();

      }
    };
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);







freezerApp.controller('freezerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.freezer = 
    {'freezername':'Freezer Name',
    'building':'Building',
    'floor':'Floor',
    'room':'Room',
    'shelves': 0,
    'racks': 0


    };

    $scope.add_freezer = function() {




    $scope.freezers.push(

    {'freezername': $scope.freezer.freezername,
    'building':$scope.freezer.building,
    'floor':$scope.freezer.floor,
    'room':$scope.freezer.room,
    'shelves': $scope.freezer.shelves,
    'racks': $scope.freezer.racks


    }




        );



};

  $scope.freezers = [
    {
    }


    ];



  $scope.default_freezer = $scope.freezers[0];

  $scope.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/freezers').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, $scope.freezers);
    });
  }; 




}]);
```

Comment: have you already confirmed database response in your controller without using resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ui-Router Resolve Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value **before the controller is instantiated** and the $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.

It looks like you are trying to provide `$scope` object from your `freezerCtrl` to your resolve property. This is incorrect.

I would recommend you create a factory like so for your api call.

```
angular.module.('freezerApp').factory('freezerFact',function($http){
    return {
     getAll: $http.get('/freezers')
    }
});
```

Then inside of your freezer `$state` deceleration you could do it like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('freezer', {
      url: '/freezers',
      templateUrl: 'partials/freezers.html',
      controller: 'freezerCtrl',
      resolve: {
        freezerPromise: function(freezerFact){
              return freezerFact.getAll;
      }
    };
});
```

Then you would pass the `freezerPromise` object into your `freezerCtrl` and manipulate the promise after that.

Comment: Thanks!! This clarifies a lot for me, thanks. I'm basing my app largely off of a tutorial that uses a factory to store data, but thought I would try and get away with keeping it in the controller. Guess not.